# How to customize save permanently individual's data input in mobile application according to e-mail login

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, save, store

I am having difficulty saving individual's data input onto mobile applications according to their e-mail login.

Moreover, despite different e-mail login to the application, the previous login's data input can be seen.

How to customize saving data input according to different e-mail logins?

I have saved data input permanently under User default. However, I am unable to customise data save individual input data according to different e-mail login being used. Kindly help me as I am new to using X-code and Swift programming.

Attached below is the code that I use to permanently save data.

```
@IBAction func savebtn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let data =  GraphDataIngo6(date: lblfirst.text ?? "", target: lblsecond.text ?? "", amount: lblAmount.text ?? "")
    let newData = SVGraphInfoTable6()
                                 newData.date = lblfirst.text ?? ""
                                 newData.target = lblsecond.text ?? ""
                                 newData.amount = lblAmount.text ?? ""
                                
                                 
                                 var oldArray = getCurrentTableData()
                                 oldArray.append(newData)
                                 self.saveCurrentTableData(dic: oldArray)
    delegate?.onGraphReady(dataGraph: data)

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
func getCurrentTableData() -> [SVGraphInfoTable6]
                {
                    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "currentGraphTableDataSix"){
                        
                        let arrayObjc = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data)
                        return arrayObjc as! [SVGraphInfoTable6]
                    }
                    return [SVGraphInfoTable6]()
                }
            func saveCurrentTableData(dic: [SVGraphInfoTable6])
                       {
                           let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dic)
                           UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: "currentGraphTableDataSix")
                           UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                       }
```

Comment: It's unclear: How do you currently are saving these informations? Where?

Comment: Please add the code you already have so we can better help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: "currentGraphTableDataSix")`, save `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(data, forKey: "currentGraphTableDataSix\(userEmail)")`? I wouldn't save it into UserDefaults if the data is quite big but into a file instead.